# How to read files with similar names but without writting all the names? python

Tags: python, file

I have written some code, but I wish to do in a cleverer way, using a for loop to write the names instead.

My code is:

```
file_name_01 = os.path.join(input_folder_name,'subject101.dat')
file_DF_01 = pd.read_table(file_name_01, ' ',  header=None)
file_name_02 = os.path.join(input_folder_name,'subject102.dat')
file_DF_02 = pd.read_table(file_name_02, ' ', header=None)
file_name_03 = os.path.join(input_folder_name,'subject103.dat')
file_DF_03 = pd.read_table(file_name_03, ' ', header=None)
file_name_04 = os.path.join(input_folder_name,'subject104.dat')
```

But I want something like this:

```
for(i=0, i<9, i++)
    file_name_0%i = os.path.join(input_folder_name,'subject10%i.dat')
    file_DF_0%i = pd.read_table(file_name_0%i, ' ',  header=None)
```

I already looked for an answer, but I only found solutions for R, Java and other languages.

I need this in python, if somebody could help me, I will be very happy.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dynamically building up variable names, I would use a `dict`

```
files = dict()
for i in range(9):
    file_name = os.path.join(input_folder_name, 'subject10{}'.format(i))
    files[file_name] = pd.read_table(file_name , ' ',  header=None)
```

Comment: Minor nit:  Since OP's original naming convention was `file_DF_01`, `file_DF_02`, etc, perhaps a better name for the dictionary is `file_DFs` since it implies a collection of DataFrames from file.  Or even just `DFs`.  `files` implies that the dictionary contains files.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary seems to be a simple way to handle the relationship of variable names to value.

```
#New dictionary 
fileDict = {}

for i in range(1,9):
    fileName = "file_name_0"+str(i)
    fileDF = "file_DF_0"+str(i)
    subjectName = "subject10"+str(i)+".dat"

    fileDict[fileName] = os.path.join(input_folder_name,subjectName)
    fileDict[fileDF] = pd.read_table(fileDict[fileName], ' ',  header=None)
```

*Note: Your example variables start at `1` while your loop starts at `0`*

Comment: Thanks a lot! it was really helpfull!! :)